# Passing Variables to External Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, input

I have a view dynamic variables that I would like to pass to an external javascript.

in the HTML I am setting a few hidden input fields, as such:

```
<input type=hidden id="varID" value="sourceID">
```

and then calling them in my external Javascript file as such:

```
varID = document.getElementById("varID").value;
```

When I check to see if there is anything in there, I always get an undefined.  In my HTML, I am setting the hidden input field before I even al to load the external javascript file.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: Wait until the DOM is loaded in your external file before checking for the elements

Comment: use the onload() event from the html <body> tag to call a function when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Possibly related: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) Using a global variable by the same identifier as the element's `id` may be clashing with the browser's own use of globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your external JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var varID = document.getElementById("varID").value;
});
```

Comment: that did it... I don't know why... since everything else was loading properly without the document.ready.

Comment: $( document ).ready will make sure the Dom is ready before accessing any data in it. if it helps you please mark the answer.

Comment: I have to wait a minute before I can mark this correct... be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
   var varID = document.getElementById("varID").value;
}
```

Basically, the JavaScript code will only run once the page has loaded.